# Using low frequency data to calibrate high frequency data

Tags: time-series, calibration

I have a 10 Hz time series measured by a fast instrument  and a 1 minute time series measured by a slow reference instrument. The data consists of a fluctuating meteorological parameter. The slow reference instrument is used to calibrate the fast instrument measurements. Both time series are synchronised.

My idea:

- Average the 10 Hz data into 1 minute blocks.
- Take 5 one minute block from each time series and calculate the linear regression equations.
- Use the regression equations to calibrate the 10 Hz data in 5 minute blocks (3000 data points).

What would be the best way to match (calibrate) the high frequency data using the low frequency data? I use MATLAB.

More background:
The fast instrument outputs a fluctuating voltage signal while the slow instrument outputs the true value of a trace gas concentration in ppb (parts per billion). The slow instrument samples every ten seconds and outputs the average every one minute.

In short I would like to have my fast signal also in ppb but without losing it's integrity,  hence the need to use a linear fit.

Comment: In such "change of support" situations it is often useful, if not essential, to consider *what* the slow instrument is measuring.  There are differences between reporting a one-minute average, a time-weighted one-minute average, a one-minute maximum (or minimum), a "snapshot" for the middle of that minute, or a value of a random instant within that one-minute interval. Each of these would suggest a different solution. Could you clarify this for the case you're interested in?

Comment: @whuber I have tried to expand my question to include more background. In short,  my slow instrument measures the same parameter as the fast one, but at a lower resolution (10s sampling time and I minute averaging time)